# Find postgresql replica server

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6, wal

I see the message in PostgreSQL logs

> 2020-12-20 19:34:41 MSK [10090-1] replication@[unknown] ERROR:
> requested WAL segment 000000010000035D00000094 has already been
> removed

My current wal files name like
00000001000005E4000000B0

Is there any way to find out the client ip for this wal request?

I suppose some test or developer server was switched off for a long time and now it is on. I have too many connections to check them all manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add `%h` to the `log_line_prefix` parameter, and the IP address will be logged along with the error.